# Are polyhedra with equilateral triangular faces rigid?

Tags: co.combinatorics, dg.differential-geometry, discrete-geometry, isometries, isometric-immersion

Convex polyhedra are rigid by Cauchy’s theorem. Steffen’s polyhedron is an example of a non-convex polyhedron that is flexible (i.e., non-rigid). However, it appears to have edges of different lengths. My question: are there flexible polyhedra with equilateral triangular faces? I am interested in both finite and (non-trivial) infinitesimal flexibility.

Motivation: I have a bars-and-balls magnetic construction set and I would like to build a flexible polyhedron. But all the bars I have are equal in length.

Cross-posted on [math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4474324/are-equilateral-polyhedra-with-triangular-faces-rigid)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This depends on how do you define a "polyhedron".  If you accept a doubly covered lozenge (two copies of two adjacent equilateral triangles), then no.  But under reasonable nondegeneracy conditions the answer is mostly likely yes.  We worked on this problem in our recent [Domes over curves](https://arxiv.org/abs/2005.02555) paper, joint with Alexey Glazyrin (see $\S$5.2).  If there was a flexible polyhedron of this type this would disprove some conjectures in the area that we believe are true.  Anyway, your question is formalized as Conjecture 5.5 where we also have plenty of context on the subject.

P.S.  Both Alexey and I gave several Zoom talks on this paper. You can find the links [on my website](https://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Epak/papers/research.htm#gc).

Comment: Awesome. Could you please shed some light on why Conjecture 5.5 is formulated like so “if $S$ is flexible then it doesn’t flex $\gamma$“ instead of perhaps the more natural “all closed domes are rigid”. Is there a subtle (or obvious …) difference that I am missing?

Comment: Yes, I can.  That's to avoid various degenerate counterexamples like having two polyhedra attached by a rigid double edge and flexing around it, for example.  So if $\gamma$ flexes that's enough as a nondegeneracy condition and enough to imply Conj 5.1

Answer (score 3):

The [Bricard octahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bricard_octahedron) is not a polyhedron formally, but can be made from isosceles triangles; it is flexible and can be made from a bars-and-balls magnetic construction.

Comment: For more on this, see Connelly's "Flexing surfaces" in the important 1981 collection *The Mathematical Gardner* (Springer).

Comment: Being equilateral is an important constraint making Bricard octahedron construction impossible, see my answer below.

Comment: @IgorPak --- by some reason I thought ''isosceles'' --- my mistake.

Comment: "see my answer below." For some value of "below".